# Ruby on Rails show action not working from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, rendering

I used scaffolding to build my RoR app then I added another controller action called apply_configs. it is working fine (all actions I added to the controller method are executed fine and I can tell that from the logs on the server) but I can't get it to render the right page after it executes. I added the following to the end of apply_configs method in the controller file

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @l2vpn.update_attributes(params[:l2vpn])
    format.html { render action: "show", notice: 'L2vpn was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @l2vpn.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

On the server, I can see these logs

```
Started GET "/l2vpns/apply_configs? <long list of params goes here> " for 172.24.67.151 at 2012-03-16 11:32:01 -0700
Processing by L2vpnsController#apply_configs as */*
Parameters: { <long comma separated list of params goes here> }
L2vpn Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "l2vpns".* FROM "l2vpns" WHERE "l2vpns"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered l2vpns/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 112ms (Views: 12.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

but in fact, unlike the logs indicate, my browser does not display the content of show.html.erb, the browser page is unchanged. My goal is to display show.html.erb after apply_configs is executed.

Anyone has an idea how to achieve that, and why it is not working as expected for me with the above configs?

UPDATED CODE after jdl's comment

```
class L2vpnsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js, :html, :json
  # GET /l2vpns/1
  # GET /l2vpns/1.json
  def apply_configs
    @l2vpn = L2vpn.find(params[:id])

    <more code goes here>

    flash[:notice] = "Configs applied successfully!"
    respond_with(@l2vpn, :location => l2vpns_url)
  end

  <other controller action definitions go here>

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that you are not redirecting after updating your object. Take a look at [this Railscast on Rails 3 controllers](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3), specifically the parts dealing with `respond_with` which will take care of much of this work for you.

Comment: Thanks jdl. I implemented the changes like in that tutorial but I'm still getting exactly the same behavior!

Comment: Please post your new controller code, and if you're using `attr_accessible` in your model that would be good to know as well.

Comment: Thanks jdl, I pasted an updated controller code at the end of my original question

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you want to redirect to the `show` action rather than render the `show` template. By rendering the `show` template directly, you're not gathering the required data [e.g the model itself] for the template to render properly since this is done by the  `Controller.show` method.

Since I don't know how you pass the id of the affected model, i assume it's passed as a parameter named `:id`.

Your redirect would then look like, assuming you're in the same controller (otherwise, pass the controller with `:controller => 'controller'`:

```
format.html { redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => params[:id], :notice => 'L2vpn was successfully updated.' }
```

A second option [although I personally don't use it] is to actually render the show template directly, but then you'll need to duplicate (or refactor and call) most of the same code that's being run in the `Controller.show` method. More precisely, you need to run the part of the code that provide data to the view.

For example:

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id])
format.html { render action: "show", notice: 'L2vpn was successfully updated.' }
```

Comment: Thanks simonnordberg. I tried both methods but none of them worked. I can the show action executed (from the logs on the server) and I see a log saying "Rendered l2vpns/show.html.erb" but the content of that file is not displayed by my browser!

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess, change the GET request to POST and that should probably fix the problem.

I'm guessing that your "  " is more than the allowed amount of chars the GET request can have and your browser chokes on that.

Comment: @fail markdown, change the second paragraph to, I'm guessing that your "long list of params go here" ...